# In case of return statement in loops with brackets, error may reach end of non void function is shown but not in case of loops with no brackets

Tags: c++

In the first case it shows error: control reached to end of non-void function.
But in the second case, even though the code does the same thing as the first code it does not show any error. can someone walk me through as to what happens exactly in both cases in the compiler?
Also why is the return statement in case 1 not acknowlegded

```
//case 1
    int checkA(const vector<int>& a, int n, int k)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        { if(k%a[i])
                return 0;
            return 1;
        }
    }
//case 2
    int checkA(const vector<int>& a, int n, int k)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
         if(k%a[i])
                return 0;
            return 1;
    }
```

Comment: *"...code does the same thing .."* No, it doesn't. What gave you that idea?

Comment: The `return` statement in the second snippet is outside of the `for` loop and inside in the first snippet. Therefore, if `n` is `0` or smaller, the first snippet will never return anything because the loop body is not executed.

Comment: It does not do the same thing. In the first case, `return 1` is inside the loop. If the code does not enter the loop (`n` less than or equal to 0), the function returns nothing. In second case `return 1` is outside the loop, and it's perfectly okay (it's always returned).

Comment: okay. I understood. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

It does not do the same thing. If you posted the snippets with a better formatting, you'd see the following:

```
//case 1
int checkA(const vector<int>& a, int n, int k)
{
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        if(k%a[i])
            return 0;
        return 1;
    }
}
```

And case 2 is

```
//case 2
int checkA(const vector<int>& a, int n, int k)
{
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        if(k%a[i])
            return 0;
    return 1;
}
```

In case 1, you check if the first array element (`a[0]`) divides `k` and, if it does, `return 1` immediately at the same iteration. The thing is, if array has zero elements (`n` is 0), there is no first iteration at all and, consequently, no return statement is ever hit (both `return 0` and `return 1` can only happen on the first iteration).

Case 2 has a final `return 1` that only happens *after* the loop, if none of array elements triggered an earlier exit.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case you have `return 1;` unconditionally inside the loop. But if the loop doesn't run (when `n <= 0`) then you won't have a `return` statement at all. Not returning a value in a function declared to do so leads to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

In the second case, the `return 1;` is *not* part of the loop, it happens after the loop finishes.

Answer (score 1):

> in the second case, even though the code does the same thing as the first code it does not show any error.

This is incorrect. In the second case the code does something different.

> Can someone walk me through as to what happens exactly in both cases in the compiler?

Let's say you call `checkA({2,5}, 2, 2)`.

In case 1 your function does this:

- `i=0;`
- Check `i<n` (true, so the loop runs)
- Check `k%a[i]` (2%2) (false, so it doesn't return 0)
- Return 1

and the result is 1. In case 2 your function does this:

- `i=0;`
- Check `i<n` (true, so the loop runs)
- Check `k%a[i]` (2%2) (false, so it doesn't return 0)
- `i++;`
- Check `i<n` (true, so the loop runs)
- Check `k%a[i]` (2%5) (true)
- Return 0 because the check was true

In case 1 the return statement is inside the loop, so it will try to return something every time around the loop (of course, returning ends the loop). In case 2, it only returns 1 after the loop finishes.

> Also why is the return statement in case 1 not acknowlegded

Because if `n` is 0 then the loop won't run at all, and there's no return statement after the loop.

Answer (score 1):

I am a staunch proponent of using `{}` blocks under `for`, `while`, and `if` statements even when there is just one line of code. It makes code much easier to follow. Using that approach,

#### Case 1 is equivalent to:

```
int checkA(const vector<int>& a, int n, int k)
{
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
       if(k%a[i])
       {
          return 0;
       }
       // return statement in the loop outside the if statement.
       return 1;
    }

    // No return statement after the loop.
}
```

#### Case 2 is equivalent to:

```
int checkA(const vector<int>& a, int n, int k)
{
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
       if(k%a[i])
       {
           return 0;
       }
       // no return statement in the loop outside the if statement.
    }

    // return statement after the loop.
    return 1;
}
```

Hope that explains why you get the compiler error message.